# Develop android game on multiply workspaces

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Me and my 2 friends develops an android online game in Android Studio, The project game is on my PC and is synchronize with GitHub.

The problem is that the project uses my ID of google play, And we didn't success to work with my ID on different PCs and running the project.

Its even possible to work on one project with multiply PC's ?

Comment: How was it not successful? Elaborating more on errors would help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the Google Play ID (Play Console account) since you could work on and publish/update a project/APK within a single account even from different computers as long as y'all have the same APK key credentials, particularly the **KEY_STORE JKS file**.

As for open-source collaboration via GitHub, working on a single project from different computers is also possible as long as y'all use **Git** properly.